# weird result in linq to entity

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity

I am making some filters to a site where i can set area and city but i only want to show the areas and cities where there is products but the city part is giving me wrong results. I first made the query in plain MySql and that worked fine:

```
SELECT b.city, COUNT(b.city)
FROM ads AS a 
JOIN locations AS b ON b.id = a.locations_id
JOIN areas AS c ON c.id = b.areas_id
WHERE 
a.title LIKE '% mini' OR
a.title LIKE '% mini %' OR
a.title LIKE 'mini %' AND
c.id = '7ea21f5b-5c75-11e1-8809-4061869766cd'
GROUP BY b.city
```

Linq to Entities:

```
var query = (from a in db.ads
             join b in db.locations on a.locations_id equals b.id
             join c in db.areas on b.areas_id equals c.id
             where 
             a.title.Contains(" " + searchQuery) ||
             a.title.Contains(" " + searchQuery + " ") ||
             a.title.Contains(searchQuery + " ") &&
             c.id.Equals(area)
             select new {
                 b.city
             }).OrderBy(x => x.city).GroupBy(x => x.city).ToList();

return jsonOutputString.Serialize(query);
```

the linq to entity query is just returning all the cities and dont care about the area filter

Comment: If you take away the `&&` condition?

Comment: It's strange that your SQL query worked. I believe you need parentheses around title filtering: `(a.title LIKE '% mini' OR a.title LIKE '% mini %' OR a.title LIKE 'mini %') AND `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var query = (from a in db.ads
                             join b in db.locations on a.locations_id equals b.id
                             join c in db.areas on b.areas_id equals c.id
                             where 
                             (a.title.Contains(" " + searchQuery) ||
                             a.title.Contains(" " + searchQuery + " ") ||
                             a.title.Contains(searchQuery + " ")) &&
                             b.areas_id.Equals(area)
                             select new
                                        {
                                            b.city
                                        }).OrderBy(x => x.city).GroupBy(x => x.city).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked can you explain why the () is needed arround a.title?

Comment: @MikkelRefsgaard [Operator precedence and associativity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx). As you can see AND has higher priority than OR